# how to stream a video in iphone

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayer

does initWithContentURL: in MPMoviePlayerController download the video file at first and then start playing or will it stream file like in youtube?

I want to play an video located in server through streaming in order not to waste of time.

How to perform streaming in iphone?
Can anyone please suggest me if u know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

if (!documentsDirectory) {
    NSLog(@"Documents directory not found!");
}
NSString *appFile;
NSArray *myWords = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[videolistArray objectAtIndex:[number intValue]] valueForKey:@"video"]] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/"]];
appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[myWords lastObject]];
NSFileManager *fileMgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:appFile]) {
    NSData *imageData;
    NSURL *imageURL = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[videolistArray objectAtIndex:[number intValue]] valueForKey:@"video"] ] autorelease];
    if (imageURL) {
        imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    }

    [imageData writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
}
[pool release];


if (spinner) {
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [spinner removeFromSuperview];
    [spinner release];
    spinner = nil;
}
```

---------------------------Above methode is for save video in file system of iphone
-------------------- Below method to play that movie continuos

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

if (!documentsDirectory) {

    NSLog(@"Documents directory not found!");

}

NSArray *myWords = [videoString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/"]];


NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[myWords lastObject]];

NSLog(@"%@",[myWords lastObject]);

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile];

self.videoMPPlayer =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    self.videoMPPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    self.videoMPPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    self.videoMPPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;


    // Register for the playback finished notification

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(movieLoadStateChanges:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:videoMPPlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoMPPlayer];


// Movie playback is asynchronous, so this method returns immediately.
[self.videoMPPlayer play];
```

Comment: Hi., thank you, for the answer, do we have to download the complete file before start playing?is it not possible to download as streaming? is there any option other than MPMoviePlayer for streaming video file?

Comment: for this just use the following code from NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"Link of vidoe"];

Comment: converting url string to NSURl and if i used in initWithContentURL: , the movie player starts play after getting data from the webservice, till that time player doesnot play anything, I need get video file data from webservice and also play the retrieved data simultaneously, as like youtube retrieves data and plays simultaneously.

Comment: have you give interview in the morning ?

Comment: no. i didnt,where it happened? do u get any idea of retrieving data and playing like in youtube?

Comment: just pass your url to webview its will play video like youtube

Comment: thank you, i will use it.., till now i am thinking MPMoviePlayer wont do streaming, i get it, that it supports streaming, thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Hi, please help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432043/how-to-relay-h-264-stream :)