# How to relay h.264 stream?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, h.264, mpeg-2

I have 2 servers, server2 can receive h.264 stream from server1. I need my iPad can play the h.264 stream, and my ipad and server2 are in the same local area network， but can not connect to server1, so I need server2 relay the h.264 stream to my ipad, who has one good solution ? thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your question is rather vague.

If you are playing via HLS then you could install an HTTP proxy on server2.

Apache even has a proxy module which lets you make a URL on server1 appear as if it was hosted by server2 without having to configure your iPad to use server2 as its proxy.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

See the bit about reverse proxy.